# Dynamic filename in Mapping Data Flow sink without the column in file

Tags: azure-data-factory

The way I understand it, is if you want to have dynamic filenames when writing to blob storage from a mapping data flow, the solution is to set "As data in column" on the file name options on the sink. This then uses the contents of a column as the filename for each row. To set the filename in the row you can have a derived column that contains the expression.

With auto mapping enabled on the sink this then results in having a column in the file containing the filename.

With auto mapping turned off, I could map all columns except for this one, but as I want to also have schema drift enabled on the source and keep any extra columns in the destination I can't have a fixed set of output columns.

How can I dynamically set the filename that gets generated without including it as a column in the file?
Or if we assume every row will have the same filename is there another way to dynamically set a filename? I've struggled to find any documentation on the file name options, but Pattern looks like it just adds a number and single file looks like a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

When you choose 'Output to single file' option, you can create a `parameter` in Data Flow and use it as file name. Then pass the value from pipeline to Data Flow like this:

My test:

1.add a parameter in Data Flow.
[image]

2.use that parameter as file name.
[image]

3.pass the value to parameter.

[image]

[image]